# Error: method in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: methods

How do I get rid of this error?

It says:

```
required: double, double
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Code:

```
public double computeBMI(double kg, double meter)
{
    double bmin;

    bmin= kg/(meter*meter);

    return bmin;
}

public static void main (String args[])
{
    BMI obj = new BMI();    
    double bmin = obj.computeBMI();  //error appears here the period is highlighted.
    obj.checkStatus(bmin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `computeBMI` method requires two `doubles`. You are not passing any, try entering two `doubles` in the empty brackets on your error line. The error message tells you just that.